# How can I remove an object from a shot?

Tags: premiere, video-editor, editing

I’m attempting to remove a head mounted GoPro in a mirror shot, exactly as seen in this video, around the 15 second mark:

I’m using premier pro cc 2018, and I’m just looking for some ideology, or methodology on how to do so. Obviously a clear cut solution would be ideal. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object removal is usually done by masking, tracking and inserting a clean plate into the masked area.
Easier done in After Effects than in Premiere.

It looks like in the above video it is a different shot inserted into the mirror.

Comment: Right of course! Just insert & conform a separate shot into the mirrors boundaries. Didn’t think of that haha.